# tilde ~ not showing in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, cs50

I've started CS50 (for those who knows) and I'm currently implementing a codespace in VSCode. After executing `ssh-keygen`, I have to execute `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. However, the tilde '~' does not appear in the vscode terminal and therefore I can't set up the space. Does anyone has an idea to solve the problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: use the key bind debugging to find out where the key is landing

Comment: I don't understand what I'm supposed to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved : instead of the tilde I put a dot